# How to copy folder from src/main/resources to a dynamic location in Java?

Tags: java, file, directory, java-11, java.nio.file

I've a folder with name "test" and has many folders and files inside it. I've to copy this folder to a dynamic location in Java. Below is the code I've written:

```
class FileManager {
    public static void copy(Path path) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = FileManager.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test");
        Files.copy(inputStream, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
}
```

This is copying to the location but not copying as a folder, but as a file. The path string I'm sending is "C:/Users/test". Most importantly I want this code working in jar. I cannot get the physical location of the "test" folder in the jar.

Comment: There is no simple way to do this, because there is no actual folder named "test".  Jar files are zip files and do not have directories, just a sequence of entry names that happen to look like hierarchical file names.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188427/how-to-copy-folders-out-of-resources-from-jar-both-in-runtime-and-dev-env/56189875.

Comment: You can't list the resources inside a Jar file that easy. The common way is not to include multiple files into the resources, but one ZIP file that contains all files you want to extract. Using `ZipInputStream` you can then extract those files to the target directory.