# List all the files inside resources folder

Tags: java

How can I get a list of files inside the `resources` folder in Java?

[image]

This is not a `resources` folder from `test` folder, also my `.jar` file doesn't contain the `resources` folder so I don't think `ZipInputStream` is a solution? (I'm using maven to build my `jar`)

I tried `Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();` to list all the file, but how can I efficiently filter out `entries` that's not from the `resources` folder? (such as class file or folder contains class files...)

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The resources folder of your project is a static folder. The content does not change. So you know exactly the content of the resources folder at the time you are developing your application.

Comment: How are you deploying this? If the folder isn't in your `.jar`, then it won't be there when someone else runs your code. Are you planning to deliver the `resources` folder separately with your software?

Comment: “my .jar file doesn't contain the resources folder” Are you expecting this to run on any computer other than your own?  It seems to me that if your resources aren’t part of your .jar file, you’ll need to distribute the resource directory along with the .jar file.

Comment: @VGR Sorry, English is not my native language. Files inside the `resources` folder in the project are in the `.jar`, but not inside a folder called `resources`, [here is the image](https://i.imgur.com/62u50WU.png). My goal is to get a list of files that is from the `resources` folder.

Comment: The short answer is:  you can’t.  The longer answer is:  there are ways that will work, but they are not reliable.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188427/how-to-copy-folders-out-of-resources-from-jar-both-in-runtime-and-dev-env.  The full answer is:  do as McPringle suggested and keep a plain text file as an additional resource, which contains a list of your other resources.  It’s your application, so you know exactly which resources are in it.

Comment: You can write a small Java application to create that file list using File.listFiles and scanning the content of your resource folder. Run this as a test case during your build, so it is always up to date.